# Python Requests Programmatically get Dev Tools Form Data pre-formatted as a dictionary

Tags: python, http, automation, python-requests

I am trying to update an already saved form on a system using HTTP requests. Due to the server configuration for the third party app we use, updating by POST requires sending a fully filled out payload every single time.

I want to get round this by recovering the form data already present on the server and converting it into a dictionary. Then changing any values I need and reposting to make changes sever side.

The application we use sends a POST request when the save button is clicked for a particular form.

Here I send a post request with no payload. 
[This simulates pressing the save button and is also the point where dev tools shows me a the payload I want to capture]

```
post_test = self.session.post(url_to_retrieve_from)
```

I thought that now I should be able to print the output, which should resemble what Google Dev tools Form data captures.

```
print(post_test.text)
```

This just gives me html found on the webpage.

If Dev Tools can get this from the server then I should also be able to?

Example of Data I am trying to get via requests: 
[Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZLQv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> If Dev Tools can get this from the server then I should also be able to?

Yes, of course. In requests you pass form data in **data** keyword:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com'

data = {
    'name': 'value',
}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

You can get the data you sent with a request from the response in this way:

```py
import requests

response = requests.post('http://your_url', data=data) # send request

body = response.request.body

parsed_data = dict(data.split('=') for data in body.split('&')) # parse request body
```

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post) you can find more information about *data* argument

In the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api), in the class *requests.Response* we can find the attribute:

> request = None
>
> The PreparedRequest object to which this is a response.

In [*requests.PreparedRequest*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) class we can read:

> body = None
>
> request body to send to the server.

Comment: I have not been able to get the desired results from this code yet(the isolated code does not compile). Would you be able to point me to the docs/api docs where I can read about **request.body** in particular

Comment: I think I understand.  Here you send a post request and convert it from a response object to a prepared request object to use `.body`. Except the response is not sending me the data I want. I think this is because the HTTP POST request being sent when the save btn is pressed, is taking the data in real time from the form fields on the front end content management website.

Comment: I've just found a mispelling. The code is correct now. Could you try it again?

Comment: Okay thks for editing the code. Currently body returns None this might be due to my url and data argument not being correct. I will keep testing this to hopefully make it work

Comment: I found a GET API call which gives me some html for a particular product instance I am looking for. So parsing that using beautiful soup is actually giving me the data I need.